# Alternative to "Display:-webkit-flex" for Chrome Mobile

Tags: css, flexbox

Lately I've been working on a mobile optimised web platform utilising HTML5/CSS3. This application has a landing page which consists of four equally sized tiles with an Icon in the middle (some other styles like a bit of padding in between them and border radius etc). These tiles are sized based on the screen size using "*display: flex;*" obviously due to the nature of the user being able to change the screen orientation.

I'm achieving this using the following markup...

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">        
    <a href="1.aspx">
        <span class="icon1"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="2.aspx">
        <span class="icon2"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="3.aspx">
        <span class="icon3"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="4.aspx">
        <span class="icon4"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    }   

    .container a {
        -webkit-flex: 1 1 48%;
        flex: 1 1 48%;
        margin: 1%;
        position: relative;

        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
           -moz-border-radius: 8px;
                border-radius: 8px;

        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

I've run into a rather frustrating issue whereby this **doesn't** display properly at all on Chrome Mobile (works on Beta, not on current version) on either iOS or Android.

Basically I'm looking to re-write the CSS to achieve exactly the same layout but I'm having difficulty finding another way to do it, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: ah, the perils of being at the bleeding edge.  :-(  but +1 for a good clear question, and also for doing the right thing and providing the non-prefixed versions of all your styles as well as the prefixed ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself using the following markup.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="landingwrap">
        <div class="landingstrip">
            <div class="landingicon-wrap">
                <a Class="landingicon landingicon-tl">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="landingicon-wrap">
                <a Class="landingicon landingicon-tl">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="landingstrip">
            <div class="landingicon-wrap">
                <a Class="landingicon landingicon-tl">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="landingicon-wrap">
                <a Class="landingicon landingicon-tl">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
     background: #222;

}
.landingwrap {

    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
.landingstrip {
    height: 50%;
}
.landingicon-wrap {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.landingicon {
    background-color: #2aace2;
    position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Works a treat. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/ch7n6/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Beta is likely to support a recent re-draft of the functionality (which you're using in your code), whereas older browsers (ie the ones not currently in beta!) went by a different syntax. There's a good article on this [here](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/). Meanwhile, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) is great for a quick check on what supports what.